# pandas apply using min/max executes slowly over variable rolling window

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, max

I'm calculating values over a time series (represented through *myvalues*). The code below identifies the locations where an event happens (*cross_indices*), then counts the last 8 events (*n_crosses*). The index of the 8th cross relative to each row's time is set in the Series *max_lookback*.

The total code only takes ~0.5 seconds to set *max_lookback*. However, when I run *pd.apply()* to get minimum and maximum of *myvalues* from the current index to the *max_lookback*, the code takes ~22 seconds to run.

I thought *apply()* was supposed to rip through rows much faster than a for loop. Why is the code taking so long to execute, and how can dramatically I speed it up?

Program output is

> total time of minmax is 22.469 seconds
>
> total runtime is 22.93 seconds

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

complete_start = timeit.default_timer()
indices = pd.Series( range(20000), name='Index')
sample_from = np.append(np.zeros(9), 1) #10% odds of selecting 1
cross = pd.Series( np.random.choice( sample_from, size=len(indices) ), name='Cross' )
#cross = pd.Series( 
cross_indices = np.flatnonzero( cross )
n_crosses = 8

def set_max_lookback(index):
        sub = cross_indices[ cross_indices <= index ]    
        #get integer index where crosses occurred

        if len( sub ) < n_crosses:
            return int( 0 )

        return int( sub[ len(sub) - n_crosses ] )

max_lookback = pd.Series( indices.apply( set_max_lookback ), name='MaxLookback' )

start = timeit.default_timer()
myvalues = pd.Series( np.random.randint(-100,high=100, size=len(indices) ), name='Random' )

def minmax_of_zero_crosses(index):

     sub = myvalues.iloc[ range( max_lookback[index], index+1 ) ]
     return ( sub.min(), sub.max() )
    
minmax_as_tuple_series = pd.Series( indices.apply( minmax_of_zero_crosses ), name='Min' )
minmax_df = pd.DataFrame( minmax_as_tuple_series.tolist() )
minmax_df.columns = [ 'Min', 'Max' ]
maxz = minmax_df['Max']
minz = minmax_df['Min']
end = timeit.default_timer()
print('total time of minmax is ' + str(end-start) + ' seconds.')
complete_end = timeit.default_timer()
print('total runtime is ' + str(complete_end-complete_start) + ' seconds.')
```

---

Edit 1

Based on Mitch's comment, I double checked the max_lookback setting. Using n_crosses=3, you can see that the correct index of 19,981 is selected for row 19,995. The column labels, not seen on the picture, are index, myvalues, cross, max_lookback.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([myvalues, cross, max_lookback, maxz, minz ] ).transpose()
print(df.tail(n=60))
```

[image: n_crosses=3]

Using the image as an example, for row 19,999, I'd want to find min/max of myvalues between row 19,981 (max_lookback column) and 19,999, which is -95 and +97.

Comment: Contrary to what you've heard, row-wise apply is almost never the efficient solution. It isn't vectorized, and effectively a for-loop under the hood.

Comment: Also, are you certain that this is working correctly at the moment? I'm questioning your `max_lookback` values... they are not propagating back to 8 events ago as far as I can tell.

Comment: Replacing apply() with a for loop increases the time to ~27 seconds.

I just double checked the max lookback values by creating a small screenshot. I'll edit the post to confirm the work.

Comment: Yes, sure, apply is _slightly_ faster. Nevertheless, the performance gain you'll see with a vectorized solution will be _enormously_ larger. I'm just trying to piece together what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Ahh nevermind, I see how you're using `max_lookback`. Taking a look now.

Comment: The [for loop](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L4416) in `apply`, though it has various tests to see if it can do it quicker ways (data frame is a single type, the function is a native NumPy function, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` is actually not a very efficient solution at all generally, as it is effectively just a for-loop itself under the hood.

A vectorized approach:

```
indices = pd.Series(range(20000))
sample_from = np.append(np.zeros(9), 1) #10% odds of selecting 1
cross = pd.Series(np.random.choice(sample_from, size=indices.size))
myvalues = pd.DataFrame(dict(Random=np.random.randint(-100, 
                                                      100,                       
                                                      size=indices.size)))

n_crosses = 8
nonzeros = cross.nonzero()[0]
diffs = (nonzeros-np.roll(nonzeros, n_crosses-1)).clip(0)
myvalues['lower'] = np.nan
myvalues.loc[nonzeros, 'lower'] = diffs
myvalues.lower = ((myvalues.index.to_series() - myvalues.lower)
                   .fillna(method='ffill')
                   .fillna(0).astype(np.int))
myvalues.loc[:(cross.cumsum() < n_crosses).sum()+1, 'lower'] = 0

reducer = np.empty((myvalues.shape[0]*2,), dtype=myvalues.lower.dtype)
reducer[::2] = myvalues.lower.values
reducer[1::2] = myvalues.index.values + 1
myvalues.loc[myvalues.shape[0]] = [0,0]
minmax_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'min':np.minimum.reduceat(myvalues.Random.values, reducer)[::2],
     'max':np.maximum.reduceat(myvalues.Random.values, reducer)[::2]}
)
```

This yields the same min/max DataFrame as your current solution. The basic idea is to generate bounds for the min/max for each index in `myvalues`, then use [`ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to calculate those min/maxes.

On my machine, your current solution takes ~ 8.1 **s** per loop, whereas the solution above takes ~ 7.9 **ms** per loop, for around a 1025% speedup.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of [Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4686625/mitch)'s excellent work. I added comments to the code as it took me a substantial amount of time to understand the solution. I also found some minor issues.

The solution depends on numpy's [reduceat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

indices = pd.Series(range(20000))
sample_from = np.append(np.zeros(2), 1) #10% odds of selecting 1
cross = pd.Series(np.random.choice(sample_from, size=indices.size))
myvalues = pd.DataFrame(dict(Random=np.random.randint(-100, 
                                                      100,                       
                                                      size=indices.size)))

n_crosses = 3

#eliminate nonzeros to speed up processing
nonzeros = cross.nonzero()[0]

#find the number of rows between each cross
diffs = (nonzeros-np.roll(nonzeros, n_crosses-1)).clip(0)

myvalues['lower'] = np.nan
myvalues.loc[nonzeros, 'lower'] = diffs

#set the index where a cross occurred
myvalues.lower = myvalues.index.to_series() - myvalues.lower

#fill the NA values with the previous cross index
myvalues.lower = myvalues.lower.fillna(method='ffill')
#fill the NaN values at the top of the series with 0
myvalues.lower = myvalues.lower.fillna(0).astype(np.int)

#set lower to 0 where crossses < n_crosses at the head of the Series
myvalues.loc[:(cross.cumsum() < n_crosses).sum()+1, 'lower'] = 0

#create a numpy array that lists the start and end index of events for each
# row in alternating order
reducer = np.empty((myvalues.shape[0]*2,), dtype=myvalues.lower.dtype)
reducer[::2] = myvalues.lower
reducer[1::2] = indices+1
reducer[len(reducer)-1] = indices[len(indices)-1]


myvalues['Cross'] = cross

#use reduceat to dramatically lower total execution time
myvalues['MinZ'] = np.minimum.reduceat( myvalues.iloc[:,0], reducer )[::2]
myvalues['MaxZ'] = np.maximum.reduceat( myvalues.iloc[:,0], reducer )[::2]

lastRow = len(myvalues)-1

#reduceat does not correctly identify the minimumu and maximum on the last row
#if a new min/max occurs on that row. This is a manual override

if myvalues.ix[lastRow,'MinZ'] >= myvalues.iloc[lastRow, 0]:
    myvalues.ix[lastRow,'MinZ'] = myvalues.iloc[lastRow, 0]

if myvalues.ix[lastRow,'MaxZ'] <= myvalues.iloc[lastRow, 0]:
    myvalues.ix[lastRow,'MaxZ'] = myvalues.iloc[lastRow, 0]    

print( myvalues.tail(n=60) )
```